# Do Sklearn's SAG and lbfgs penalize the intercept?

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression

We know that penalizing intercept in sklearn implementation is a "design mistake" that we have to deal with. One work around is to set `intercept_scaling` to a very large number, per the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression):

> Note! the synthetic feature weight is subject to l1/l2 regularization as all other features. To lessen the effect of regularization on synthetic feature weight (and therefore on the intercept) intercept_scaling has to be increased.

However, same documentation says that this parameter is useful only when `solver='liblinear'`.

***My question:***

Do other solvers penalise the intercept? I tried to look at the source and I think they don't but I am not sure and I couldn't find clear answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solver of `LogisticRegression` that penalizes the intercept is "liblinear".

See the [official documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression):

[image]

Comment: I went deep into the source code and I just missed the obvious. Thank you very much! :)